# How can I replace certain labels with NA across multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to import a dataset from SPSS with certain levels of a factors defined as missing (f.e. no answer and unknown). Then I would like to replace these levels with `NA` so that I can perform a `tbl_summary` without these missing levels showing up.

In the past this has worked wonderfully by using `mutate(across(where(is.factor()),~na_if(.,"uknown")` and `droplevels()`. However the newer version of `dplyr` does not seem to work as I always get the following error:

> Can't convert from `y`  to `x` <factor<81b1d>> due to loss of generality. If someone could help me out, I would be extremely grateful as I am losing my mind over this....

I tried the solution suggested in:
[error in `na_if()`: ! Can't convert `y` <character> to match type of `x` <double>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75462299/error-in-na-if-cant-convert-y-character-to-match-type-of-x-double)

but it does not seem to work for me.

Comment: This is your first apparent question in 1+  years, so ... welcome to SO! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.